# Handling the "android.action.send" intent in the manifest

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, intentfilter

I'm trying to create an app that is visible in the share menu in other apps. My manifest looks like this:

```
<application android:label="MyApp">
  <activity android:name="com.MyApp.MyApp.ShareActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
```

But when I try to share something with the app, it throws an error:

```
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.MyApp.MyApp/com.MyApp.MyApp.ShareActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.MyApp.MyApp.ShareActivity" on path:...
```

I'm writing the app in C# with Visual Studio, my `ShareActivity` just looks like this:

```
public class ShareActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW, `com.MyApp.MyApp.ShareActivity` does not match `com.Air.App.ShareActivity`. That might just be in how you adjusted your question to hide your package name, though.

Comment: You're right, edited it